# How to show a picture stored as an pouchDB attachment using Angular in Ionic app

Tags: ionic-framework, pouchdb

I'm making a mobile app using Ionic and pouchDB. In the DB I keep users data with their photos stored as attachments.
I want to make a list with users photos and names.
With getting names I have no problem but I can't figure out how to show the users photo in the list.

Records in the database look like this:

```
{
  "_id": "1458320559128",
  "_rev": "2-cc9bc75fffa165497a5448e63d7bc21f",
  "firstName": "John",
  "familyName": "Doe",
  "gender": "male",
  "email": "sgasd@dfdfvg.ds",
  "phone": "423156523",
  "address": "blah",
  "country": "Venezuela",
  "city": "Whatever",
  "_attachments": {
    "johndoe947.jpg": {
      "content_type": "image/jpeg",
      "revpos": 2,
      "digest": "md5-Cw5m/SPn/cwtIguKKTcJDg==",
      "length": 24296,
      "stub": true
    }
  }
}
```

To show the list I use this view:

```
<ion-view view-title="Admin Area">
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item class="item-remove-animate item-avatar item-icon-right" ng-repeat="customer in customers" type="item-text-wrap" href="#/tab/customers/{{ customer.id }}">
            <img ng-src="{{customer.photo}}">
            <h2>{{customer.firstName}} {{customer.familyName}}</h2>
            <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

And I retrieve the date using this controller:

```
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, PouchDB) {

  $scope.customer = {};
  $scope.customers = [];
  var attachments;

  localDB.allDocs({
    include_docs: true,
    attachments: true
  }).then(function(result) {
    for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
      attachments = result.rows[i].doc._attachments;
      if (typeof attachments === 'undefined') { //if there is no attachment I put standard avatar. And this actually works OK.
        var attch = "/img/nobody.jpg";
      } else {
        for (photoFileName in attachments) { break; }   //so I take the first attachment if there was more...

        //this part is a mistery (and of course doesn't work) - how can I get attachment from the DB and directly show it on the page?
        attch = localDB.getAttachment(result.rows[i].doc.id, photoFileName)
          .then(function (blob) {
            var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            var img = document.createElement('img');
            img.src = url;
            return img;
          }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
          });
      }


      var obj = {
        "id": result.rows[i].doc._id,
        "firstName": result.rows[i].doc.firstName,
        "familyName": result.rows[i].doc.familyName,
        "attch": attch
      }
      $scope.customers.push(obj);
      $scope.$apply();
    }
  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

I was reading PouchDB documentation many times and using their examples I made something working to some extend. But it's not what I want:

```
$scope.showPic = function(id) {
    localDB.get(id, {attachments: true}).then(function(doc) {
      attachments = doc._attachments;
      for (photo in attachments) { break; }
    }).then(function() {
      return localDB.getAttachment(id, photo);
    }).then(function (blob) {
      var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      var img = document.createElement('img');
      img.src = url;

      var elem = document.getElementById(elemid);
      elem.appendChild(img);

    }).catch(function (err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
```

Using this above I can actually put a photo into some element with ID elemid when I call the function in the view like this: {{ showPic(id) }}
But I don't think it's a good way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say this is more of an Angular question than a PouchDB question, but I'll try to answer.

Basically PouchDB is giving you a method that asynchronously provides a URL to an image:

```
doStuff().then(function (blob) {
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  // now I have a url
});
```

I.e. this is the same thing that would happen if your remote server was giving you a URL somehow (e.g. via `$http`). I find it helps to think of PouchDB as a remote server, since it's asynchronous.

Now, instead of attaching the image URL directly to the `<img>` tag, you can attach it to your scope and then update the scope:

```
myScope.imgTag = url;
$rootScope.$apply();
```

Then you just have an HTML block like:

```
<img src="myScope.imgTag"/>
```

Note that if you wrap PouchDB's promises in `$q.when()`, then the `$rootScope.$apply()` is done automatically for you. Good luck!

Comment: What about Angular2 ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using ionic 1.3 pouchDB syncing with couchDB but unable to display images see example here:.

[image]

**Controller**:

```
$pouchDB.getAttachmentById('main','bares.jpg').then(function(response) {
var url = URL.createObjectURL(response);
$scope.imgTag = url;

console.log("attachments teste:")
//console.log(response);
console.log($scope.imgTag);

});
```

**Service**:

```
this.getAttachmentById = function(docId, attName) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    console.log("getAttachmentById: " + docId+" " + attName)
    database.getAttachment(docId,attName).then(function(response) {
      deferred.resolve(response);
      console.log("/************ ");
      console.log(response);
      console.log("**************/");
    }).catch(function(error) {
    deferred.reject(error);
});
return deferred.promise;
```

}

**View**:

```
html
img src="scope.imgTag"
```

**console.log:**

> attachments teste: controllers.js:60
>   blob:http://localhost:8101/a37abb3d-60b1-45a6-9c7c-6516a7c83fce

Comment: Is this an answer or question?